# Google Drive/Google Photos Automatic Subfolders by Year

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

This is driving me more than a little insane.

Anything my wife backs up to Google Photos is neatly sorted and categorized into subfolders by year in her linked Google Drive. It's been this way for a few years now.

Mine doesn't do this; it's all just a clusterfudge of everything.

I've very recently set her mother's account to back up photos to Google Photos and, in turn, Drive. Hers, too, sorts them to automatically-generated subfolders by year.

Why is it doing this for them? How do I get it do behave this way for me? I've revisited this issue off and on for more than a year with my wife's account, and now, with her mother's brand-new account, to see it behaving as I've always wanted mine to, I'm at my wit's end.

Does anyone have *any* insights regarding this?

Comment: Are you backing up your photos from a smartphone?

Comment: Sometimes, but also from my PC or laptop. The only solution I found was to start a new account and upload them through there, after which they were automatically sorted for me.

Answer (score 2):

Hey you need to enable "Automatically put Google photos into a folder in 'My drive'". Option in your Google drive settings.

Open Google Drive in app or website > settings > Google photos (section) > turn on "Automatically put Google photos into a folder in 'My drive'". Option.

Give it a day to update.

If haven't worked then then try uninstalling and reinstalling Google photos application in your smartphone.

[image: Google Drive for android application settings]

Comment: I've had that on my original account for a while now, and tried toggling it on and off through the past few months, with no discernible difference.

I just migrated everything to another account. That seems to be the only real 'fix'.